# data object not rendering in svelte component

Tags: javascript, components, svelte, svelte-component

I'm trying to set up one of my d3 projects. I am importing the data into App.svelte, then passing it to the `<Draw/>` component. Inside Draw.svelte I have `export let data = []` but when I try to use data, it is undefined & an empty array. What am I doing wrong? Here's the App.svelte code. The `console.log()`  does show the data object I'm looking for.

```
<script lang="ts">
   import Draw from "./Components/Draw.svelte"
   import { data } from './data';
   console.log(data);
</script>

<main>
   <h1>Hello </h1>
   {#await data}
       <p>Loading...</p>
   {:then data} 
       <Draw
         data={data}
       />
   {/await}
</main>
```

Comment: Can we see what's in `{ data } from ./data`? It should be a proper `Promise<Array<...>>` object.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing the closing `{/await}`. Also, it's confusing to call the variable in `{:then data}` `data` which is the same name as the promise `data`. So you're better off calling that different and then use `<Draw data={myDifferentName}/>`

Summed up, I'd rewrite your code as follows:

```html
<script lang="ts">
   import Draw from "./Components/Draw.svelte"
   import { data } from './data';
   console.log(data);
</script>

<main>
   <h1>Hello </h1>
   {#await data}
      <p>Loading...</p>
   {:then dataValue} 
      <Draw data={dataValue}/>
   {/await}
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I realized my whole code didn't copy (including the await). I had tried doing data={data} at first, but that didn't work. So essentially my code looked like your above except for renaming data to dataValue, and even with that change it doesn't work.

Comment: So, are you sure that `data` is actually a promise? Or is it maybe a function returning a promise?

Comment: `data` is just an array of objects. I tried without the await/then but that also didn't work.

Comment: If data is just an array of objects you definitely should remove await/then

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct. I guess you'll have a promise to get the `data` array, otherwise there is no much sense to use `await`. You haven't shown the `Draw` component, it's likely the problem is there. Try this to debug the `data` and make sure it's defined when the promise is resolved, before passing it to the `Draw`:

```js
<script lang="ts">
   import Draw from "./Components/Draw.svelte"
   import { data } from './data'
   console.log(data)
</script>

<main>
   <h1>Hello </h1>
   {#await data}
       <p>Loading...</p>
   {:then data}
       { console.log(data) }
       <Draw { data }/>
   {/await}
</main>
```